# Can Cordova files be uploaded by javascript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cordova, file-upload, camera

It's my first question on StackOverflow, so please be gentle! :)

I'm using Cordova (2.4.0rc1) to upload camera pics to Amazon. I found a nice uploader s3_direct_uploader ([s3_direct_uploader 0.0.8](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload)) and got it working and integrated with my Rails server. Now I'm trying to do the same with my Cordova-based "browser-with-camera".

I can get the camera to take a picture, and can get that resulting file URI, and then call fileEntry.file() which gets me something that looks like a File object (but is in fact just an object of type Object).

When I try to pass that file-like object to S3 direct uploader, I get the correct # of bytes uploaded to Amazon, but the actual file on Amazon is simply the text "[object Object]".

Is it possible for me to proceed in this direction? Can I trick  WebView into creating a real file object that points to the actual picture? (Note: for memory reasons, I don't want to load the picture into memory and then create a Blob.) Or do I have to figure out how to get Cordova's File Uploader to CORS to Amazon?

Thanks in advance for your answers and suggestions on how I can improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to trick WebView into creating a real file object that points to the actual picture. This is apparently a security feature.

Instead, I ended up using Cordova's File Upload mechanism to transfer the file to Amazon using the header information provided by s3_direct_uploader. That is the best direction to go.